# Getting error while assigning value to a list index

Tags: django

```
empname = Leave.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)[0].emp_id_requested_for
                       typelist = TypeAssign.objects.filter(emp_id__emp_name=empname)
output = {}

data = Leave.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)

for x in data:
    output[x.leave_type_id] = [0,0]

for t in data:
    output[t.leave_type_id][0] = (t.total_approve_leave + output[t.leave_type_id][0])

for x in typelist:
    **output[LeaveType.objects.get(type_name=x)][1] = LeaveType.objects.get(type_name=x).max_duration**

ctx["output"] = output

return ctx
```

Comment: KeyError :  in this line  output[LeaveType.objects.get(type_name=x)][1] = LeaveType.objects.get(type_name=x).max_duration

Comment: `LeaveType.objects.get(type_name=x)` returns a `LeaveType` object. But the index seems LeaveType's id. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: Also the code will break if the matching object doesn't exist.

Comment: the "out" dict format is  "key":[0,0] since i need only 2 types value.Then i am appending values to the indexes

Comment: I'm saying that `key` seems like `id`. But on that line you're using a `LeaveType` object as `key`. try `output[LeaveType.objects.get(type_name=x).id][1]`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you mean:

```
output[LeaveType.objects.get(type_name=x).id][1]
```

as the keys you've set elsewhere have been IDs, not LeaveType instances.

Generally your code would be clearer if you used intermediate variables rather than doing the calls inside the dict lookups.

Comment: getting keyerror again i put a attribute Exception Value:  

u'Casual'

Comment: +1 to Daniel's answer. Try to debug your code by really using intermediate variables, it will be easier for you to spot the error if you take your code step by step.

Comment: I believe @Daniel's code should be: `output[LeaveType.objects.get(type_name=x).leave_type_id][1]`

Comment: @themanatuf No, `x` and `t` are instances of `Leave`, which presumably has a ForeignKey pointing at `LeaveType`. `LeaveType` itself wouldn't have a `leave_type_id` field.

Comment: Ah, right on, looks like `t` and `x` are from `data` which is a `Leave` object. I overlooked that.

Comment: But if i do like output[LeaveType.objects.get(type_name=x)] = LeaveType.objects.get(type_name=x).max_duration  .. it does work ..